First operating system with system calls
Which first operating system implemented system calls? It should answer to the following characteristic I guess: resident program which exposes low level services (doesn't matter what be it read the clock or write to file) to user programs so the code for the service should not be linked directly to the program.
Also it shouldn't be protected by ring-based security or something similar. Just something that programmer may assume always provided to him when his program is loaded.
From my investigation, seams like it was Multics with it its daemon+dll functionality, but it seems to me too late for such a basic thing.

Isn’t the purpose of an operating system to provide system calls?

@JonCuster Agree - If it doesn't provide system calls, it can hardly be an OS.

Every OS Must provide system calls, if only a co-operative multitasking relinquish.  The question is ridiculous in its current form.

This is probably answered by this Q&A.

@Chenmunka no, early operating systems didn’t have system calls — they didn’t provide services usable by programs running on the system.

It depends on when a mere RTE becomes an OS.

@JonCuster it depends on definition of cause but in broadest term - no. The first OS GM-NAA I/O was concerned with running next batch job only. May concepts which are considered today as defining OS functionality have only evolved with time,

@StephenKitt thanks indeed it is helpful.

I would say that 'return to OS at end of program' is a system call.  Fortran II programs running on the 709 under the Fortran Monitor System were required to CALL EXIT rather than use the Fortran statement STOP (which probably still halted the CPU).

@dave I love that. It is the most essential operation proving the existence of a monitor software (or OS). Thus any system that shows program chaining (batch job(s)) without the chaining code being part of the user program itself would qualify as OS by above rules :)) In the end it shows that, as so often, those questions about 'firsts' are all depending on chosen attributes and thus usually self defying - or at least quite pointless.

Define "system call". Does it need a special CPU instruction? (There were plenty of OS that just used normal subroutine calls). If subroutine calls are allowed, where do you draw the line between "OS system call" and "bunch of library functions for I/O" (the library will be "resident")? One of the very first OS in 1955 (the General Motors GM-NAA I/O) was basically a bunch of I/O routines and a batch processing framework, does that count?

The fundamental issue is not "define system call", it is "define OS".  In some circles, the Atlas Supervisor is considered to be the first operating system (as distinct from batch monitors like IBSYS), and therefore the first OS was also the first OS to implement system calls.

@dirkt Any job management system that implements resident general subroutines that guest program can use freely knowing they are there will count for me. "Freely" is the key word as "return to OS" for example can be used only once.

The question doesn't actually make sense upon closer inspection. Does the boot loader count? The BIOS? UEFI? The VM that tries hard to be invisible? The execution loop in a card reader that Is programmable both by patch cables and in JCL?
